# XML Schema for analysis in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

Is it possible to use a XML Schema to check against the contents of a XML file?

For instance, in ASP.NET `web.config`, can I create a schema to check that `<customErrors mode = "On">`? This will ultimately be used in a C# app, the C# app should take in the XML document and the XML Schema and check if the XML Document violates any of the "rules" listed in the XML schema, i.e. `<customErrors mode = "Off">`

Is it possible to do the checking without any boundary to the structure of the XML file? i.e. the attribute `<customErrors>` can be within any part of the XML document and the schema will still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible**: Yes, in XML Schema 1.1 using assertions.

**Practical or recommended**: No.

XML Schema is intended to be used to validate the "structure of the XML file," as you anticipate in your question.  You can skip much of that via `xsd:any` and then use assertions to express the sort of spot-checks that you describe via XPath expressions.  However, it'd be more natural to just apply XPath expressions directly to your XML from within C#, or using Schematron, which is a standard for applying XPath expressions to do validation.

Comment: so, the approach i should take on will be something like using the XmlDocument API from C# library?

Comment: Yes, and you can find a XmlDocument tutorial that includes sample code an XPath here: [Manipulate XML data with XPath and XmlDocument (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C)